# rails4でECMAScript6を利用するためにsprockets-es6を導入したがgeneratorsが利用できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6

railsでgeneratorsを利用するために以下のgemを追加しました。

```
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sprockets-es6', require: 'sprockets/es6'
gem 'browserify-rails'
```

これで、`aseets/javascripts/`ディレクトリに`*.es6`ファイルを作成することで
es6のコードを記述することで動作することを確認できました。

しかしgeneratorsを利用しようとすると以下のエラーが発生します。

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: regeneratorRuntime
```

なにかsprockets-es6はbabelを利用しているようなので、generatorsもサポートされていると思うのですが、何かランタイムが必要なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ドキュメントには書かれていないようですが、babel の polyfill をロードする必要があるようです。

`application.js` に下記の記述を加えたら動作しました。

```
//= require babel/polyfill
```

- rails 4.2.1
- sprockets 3.2.0
- sprockets-es6 0.6.2
- browserify-rails 1.0.1